# Why node.js doesn't release memory?

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, v8

I'm trying to understand how works the GC on node.js. It seems than the v8 engine doesn't release the memory.

I made a very simple script implementing an http server and i save the memory usage into a stream every 3 seconds.

```
var http = require('http'),
fs = require('fs'),
heapdump = require('heapdump'),
memwatch = require('memwatch');


http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8888);

console.log('Server running on port 8888.');

memwatch.on('leak', function(info) {
    // look at info to find out about what might be leaking
    console.log('============= MEMWATCH ON LEAK ============\n',info)
});

memwatch.on('stats', function(stats) {
    // do something with post-gc memory usage stats
    console.log('============= MEMWATCH STATS ============\n', stats)
});

var myStream = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/logmem.log');

setInterval( function() {
    var t = new Date().getTime();

    var memUsage = process.memoryUsage();
    var str = t+';heapUsed;'+memUsage.heapUsed+';0;0;0\n'+
                t+';heapTotal;'+memUsage.heapTotal+';0;0;0\n'+
                t+';rss;'+memUsage.rss+';0;0;0\n';
    myStream.write( str );

}, 3000 );
```

I'm using the last version of node.js 0.10.33

I'm using Gatling to send request to my http server (15 requests/sec during 30s then 30 requests/sec during 30s then 100 requests/sec during 30s)

The following charts represent the `heapUsed`, `heapTotal` and `rss` given by `process.memoryUsage()`
[memory usage after 3 tests](http://i59.tinypic.com/2h2icxy.jpg)

After those tests, there is no activity on the server but the memory is not released, even after more than 1 hour.

[memory usage after 80min](http://i60.tinypic.com/qnmko5.png)

Can somebody explain me if it's the standard behaviour of the v8 memory of if there is a memory leak in my script ?

Thanks for the help

Comment: have you found a solution for this? 
I' facing a similar problem right now.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you didn't exceed the memory usage for the major collection to execute. That is not enough "old space" was converted to "new space" (http://jayconrod.com/posts/55/a-tour-of-v8-garbage-collection).

You need to force the GC to run. Most other runtimes allow a programmatic call to force the GC to run but I'm not sure about V8.

Comment: You can add `--expose-gc` to the command line and a global function `gc()` will be made available to trigger the GC synchronously.

Comment: Don't force the GC to run.  It does a fine job on its own when it needs to.